# Tensorflow multiple samples without batching

Tags: python, multithreading, tensorflow

I have a graph that unfortunately has some nodes that do not support batching.(custom ops that have yet to be fleshed out) I've been able to have multiple threads calling sess.run and throwing the data in through the feed_dict. I have now converted my data to tfrecords to properly utilize queues, but still can't find a way to tell it to run multiple instances of the graph in parallel without just having multiple threads calling sess.run(). I assume the tensorflow developers have created a more "pythonic" way to do so somewhere, but I have yet to find it. How do I do this within tensorflow?

edit: even with the data batched, the previous question stands, as my computation spends half its time on the cpu, and half on the gpu, thus regardless of batching, one will be waiting on the other for half the time. I'd like to have the graph train multiple samples asynchronously to fill that space.

edit 2: I guess I have to put pseudocode here for people who don't want to read the text above.

```
import tensorflow as tf

resultOfCPUCalculation = someCPUOnlyOP(inputData)\\does not support batching
gpuResults = aBunchOfGPUOps(resultOfCPUCalculation)
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run([gpuResults])
    //only uses 1 cpu core, and the gpu is idle while it's doing it's thing.
```

I'd like to do this in a "pipeline" manner, where as soon as the cpu op is done, it starts on another sample.

Answer (score 0):

```
import tensorflow as tf

input_example = get_input_example()
cpu_output = some_cpu_only_op(input_example)

cpu_output_batch = tf.train.batch(input_example, batch_size, num_threads)
gpu_output_batch = a_bunch_of_gpu_ops(cpu_output_batch)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
    threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)

    for i in range(num_train_steps):
        output_values = sess.run(gpu_output_batch)
        do_stuff_with(output_values)

    coord.request_stop()
    coord.join(threads)
```

`input_example` will have to be fed by a queue.

Comment: Sorry. I should have been more clear. When I say those ops don't support batching, I mean that in my actual model they simply take a single 3D tensor as input, instead of a 4D tensor where the outermost dimension is the batch. This means that, unless I'm fundamentally misunderstanding the way batching works in tensorflow, I can't use batches. thus I would like to instead simply run the graph in parallel.

Comment: Also, now that I think of it, the batching is actually irellevant, because even with batching, I would still like to somehow have multiple separate computations of the graph at once, as the first half of the graph is limited to the cpu. At the moment either the cpu is waiting for the gpu, or the gpu waiting for the cpu, I'd like to give them work while theyre waiting. I'll edit the question to add this information in.

Comment: Also, I've never seen py_func before. Wonder how I've missed it. It would have made some stuff I've already figured out now much easier.

Comment: By 'spends half of its time on the cpu' do you mean 'doing stuff not in the tensorflow graph'? If so, wrap that stuff in tf.py_func, then tensorflow will work out the rest. It will still be run on the cpu, but will make it run in parallel when possible. Not everything running in tensorflow is run on the GPU, and not everything running in non-tf code will run on the CPU.

Comment: no I mean the ops are running on the cpu but in the graph. Tensorflow can't parallelize it because it just does it's own thing and nodes underneath it are dependent on it.  when I call sess.run([training step]) it blocks until the entire thing is finished. Nothing gets parallelized. Only a single sample gets processed at a time, and gpu usage stays low. I'm looking for a way to queue up samples to run asynchronously so that while the cpu is normally idle waiting for the gpu to finish its stuff and for a new call to sess.run, other samples are being run on the cpu. I can't make this clearer.